# A word for when you ask someone to stop helping even though they have good intentions

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, present-tense

I need a verb that describes asking someone to stop helping you, even though you know they mean well, because it's not helpful. So you ask them in a way that is almost pleading. It's stronger than just asking, but it's not quite pleading.

I'm doing an analysis of a play, and one aspect of this analysis is that I have to categorize, line by line, what each character is trying to do in one action verb.
It is proving to be harder than I thought.

Comment: Would *refusing* work?

Comment: It would obviously help if you gave us the *actual* line (plus some surrounding context).

Comment: Are you looking for a word that means something in between asking and pleading (regardless of what is being asked for), or a word that specifically means refusing help?

Comment: Broadly no, there is no such term. 'Implore' might work for the tone, but it has nothing to do with the idea of asking
someone to stop helping you… in whatever circumstances.

Can you consider the tone alone, or is the idea of asking
someone to stop helping crucial?

Answer (score -1):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/implore

> **implore** verb UK  /ɪmˈplɔːr/ US  /ɪmˈplɔːr/ Add to word list  [ T + to
> infinitive ] to ask someone to do or not do something in a very
> sincere, emotional, and determined way: implore someone to do
> something. She implored her parents not to send her away to school....

> [ T ] literary to ask for something in a sincere and emotional way:
> She clasped her hands, and glancing upward, seemed to implore divine
> assistance.

Comment: The question says that they have to summarize all the intent of a line of dialogue in a single word. "implore" means that they're asking for something, but doesn't include *what* they're asking for, so I don't think it will help in this context.